# New version of Bitcoin Wallet is signed with a different key

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

[F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) is offering an update to [Bitcoin Wallet](https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet), but when I try to update, the following message is shown. I haven't found any official news from the author about this key change. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an account, but just popping in to clear this up. F-Droid repos sign all of the published apps with a separate, private key. For obvious reasons, that key is not the same as the one used by upstream.

Why don't we use the same key as upstream? Because we compile the apps ourselves, and because we can't expect upstream devs to always sign our built apks.

Long story short, this has nothing to do with upstream. You should either stick with his builds or with F-Droid's, but mixing them will result in signing key conflicts.

Comment: But what should I do now? I've only been using F-Droid builds and wish to continue doing so. Assuming you represent F-Droid, did you change your key about 2 months ago?

Comment: I doubt we changed the signature from version to version for any given package.

Are you sure you only installed from F-Droid? None of the versions in the screen show as installed. My guess is that you installed this app from upstream or from someplace else and you're trying to update it to an f-droid build, which - as expected - has a different signature.

Comment: You were right. I was using the upstream build. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no official information on the original website about this change you should not update the app.

If this version is a malware you could (and probably will) lose all your bitcoins.